# How to connect Cloud Kafka Cluster from Mule 3?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

How to connect confluent kafka cluster(Cloud) from Mule 3 kafka connector ? Because i am seeing only Bootstrap Server URL and other options for Producer and Consumer properties only. So there is no option to configure for below details.

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule  
required username='{{ CLUSTER_API_KEY }}'  
password='{{ CLUSTER_API_SECRET }}'; 
sasl.mechanism=PLAI
```

Is it possible to connect cloud cluster from Mule 3 Kafka connector ?

Appreciate your help.